# Was 'Incident 2' invariant for geographical changes?

Tags: scientology

I have a statement from the belief of Scientology:

> 75 million years ago Xenu took these thetans to Hawaii and Los Palmas where he subjected them to a kind of brain-washing called "implanting" for 36 days, in which false memories were implanted in their minds to make them servile."

Scientologists call this event "Incident 2"

I was wondering if the locations would be the same places on Earth, namely, Hawaii and Los Palmas, according to the belief. According to my book about geography, I can see that there have been radicall changes on the Earth during the last 75 million years. The continents, and especially the Pacific and American regions, have changed dramatically.

Comment: What is the source of this statement?

Comment: @Hamlet It's paraphrasing accounts of what's supposedly revealed to Scientologists upon reaching a high level within the Scientology organization. Here's some discussion of the primary and secondary sources on this story: http://kspaink.home.xs4all.nl/fishman/ot3.html